# Filter out results in entities C# does not contain a definition for execute

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I wanted to filter out results using this command from the query, but i get this error:

[image: Execute problem]

Here is the code causing the error:

```
    private void Bookings_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();

        // Load data into Bookings. You can modify this code as needed.
        var bookingsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("bookingsViewSource")));
        var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.Date == variables.date);
        bookingsViewSource.Source = bookingsQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);

   private System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Booking> GetBookingsQuery(AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1)
    {

      EDIT
```

here it is

```
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication7.Booking> bookingsQuery = allensCroftEntities1.Bookings;
        // To explicitly load data, you may need to add Include methods like below:
        // bookingsQuery = bookingsQuery.Include("Bookings.Client").
        // For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=157380
        // Update the query to include Room.Bookings data in Bookings. You can modify this code as needed.
        bookingsQuery = bookingsQuery.Include("Room.Bookings");
        // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return bookingsQuery;
    }
```

**EDIT
BY THE WAY HERE IS A VIDEO OF MY PROBLEM IF IT HELPS**  [video of problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX22thFJF5g)

edit now im getting this error:
[image: tolist error]

Comment: Can you post the usings of this class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the merging option from a query you should use

```
((ObjectQuery)bookingsQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
```

If yoiu want the query to be executed you can call `.ToList()` that this will execute the query and your filters will be applied

your code should be like

```
var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.Date == variables.date);
((ObjectQuery)bookingsQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
bookingsViewSource.Source = bookingsQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: ather this line 
`var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.Date == variables.date);`

Comment: @Hamoudy: you're getting the error because you're calling `ToList()` to execute the query and then trying to set the `MergeOption` after the query has executed.  Call `ToList()` after setting the `MergeOption`.

Comment: but where would i call the tolist command:  var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.Date == variables.date).ToList();
            ((ObjectQuery)bookingsQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;

Answer (score 0):

There is no Execute.  The bookingsQuery will "execute" automatically as part of the data consumer iterating over the data the query defines.

Comment: so how would i be able to apply this filter?

Comment: where though, i have these lines of code, see the last screenshot: var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.Date == variables.date).ToList(); ((ObjectQuery)bookingsQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly